# MySQL procedure doesn't work properly

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write the procedure iterating over all table in the schema to make further change to all of them. however when I call it it returns this message and I can't figure out why:

Error Code: 1329. No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed

her is the procedure code itself:

```
delimiter #
drop procedure if exists myschema.create_triggers #
create procedure myschema.create_triggers()
begin
  declare tname CHAR(255);
  declare result VARCHAR(255);

  declare cTab cursor for select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'myschema';
  open cTab;
  tLoop: LOOP
    fetch cTab into tname;
    SET result = CONCAT(result, tname, ',');    
  end LOOP tLoop;

  select result;
end #
```

cursor query works fine so why this procedure doesn't do what's expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `CONTINUE HANDLER`. The continue handler tells MySQL what to do, when the cursor has processed all rows.

Examples can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html).

Quote:

> Cursor declarations must appear before handler declarations and after variable and condition declarations.

```
Example:

CREATE PROCEDURE curdemo()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE a CHAR(16);
  DECLARE b, c INT;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id,data FROM test.t1;
  DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR SELECT i FROM test.t2;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur1;
  OPEN cur2;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO a, b;
    FETCH cur2 INTO c;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    IF b < c THEN
      INSERT INTO test.t3 VALUES (a,b);
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO test.t3 VALUES (a,c);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
  CLOSE cur2;
END;
```

More information about handlers in general can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-handler.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I added this to my code but my problem persist, It doesn't do anything while the cursor query returns 13 rows. Instead of null response I expect to see all my tables delimited by colon. cursor query response: 13 row(s) returned

Comment: Please edit the new version of your procedure into the question.

Comment: I believe this line causes problem: "SET result = CONCAT(result, tname, ',');" because it returns 13 results with table name in it when put "select tname" inside the loop. So it is actually doing what I want as the final step will be replacing this line with trigger creation clause. So thanks for your help, I'm guessing I will struggle with trigger creation within the loop but that's a different story.